# A problem with using Smarty & Mysql & Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

I have a problem in using Samrtm Mysql and Jquery or Ajax
and if I use a div auto reloader
it shows a php error ..
these are my files:
accept.html (Template)

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#invite').load('accept.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
</script>
{/literal}
<div id="invite">
<fieldset>
<legend>Invites</legend>
{section name=ct loop=$invites}
You have an invite {$sender.user}<br />
<a href="?action=accept_contest&sid={$invites[ct].sendid}">Accept</a> | <a href="?action=cancel_contest&sid={$invites[ct].sendid}">Cancel</a>
{/section}
</fieldset>
</div>
```

accept.php (Main file)

```
<?php

$time = date("i:s",time("s"));
$sql_select_invite = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invite WHERE recid = '$_SESSION[id]' AND accept = '0' AND endtime > '$time'");

while($invite = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select_invite)){
 $sender = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE id = '$invite[sendid]'"));
    $contest->assign("sender", $sender);
    $invites[] = $invite;
}
$contest->assign("invites", $invites);

?>
```

and when I use the Jquery thing or Ajax
it shows this error:

> **Warning**: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   **C:\AppServ\www\somefo\accept.php**
>   on line **6**
>
> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function
>   assign() on a non-object in
>   **C:\AppServ\www\somefo\accept.php**
>   on line **11**

I don't know why it shows this .. and I hope you answer me
and what or how to solve this problem

Thanks ..

Comment: try executing `SELECT * FROM invite WHERE recid = '$_SESSION[id]' AND accept = '0' AND endtime > '$time'` directly on phpmyadmin or something like it with pre-determined values for the php variables. See if there is any result

Comment: i want a direct solve .. i mean in the file not in the phpmyadmin
and thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For php:

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_connect(......);  // connect to your server
if (!$sql) {
    die('Can\'t connect to database');
}

// select your database
mysql_select_db('your_db', $sql) or die('Can\'t select database');

$time = date("i:s",time("s"));
$sql_select_invite_query = "SELECT * FROM invite WHERE recid = '$_SESSION[id]' AND accept = '0' AND endtime > '$time'";

// print it if you want to see sql query to test it in phpmyadmin
echo $sql_select_invite_query; 
// --------------------------------------------------------------

$sql_select_invite = mysql_query($sql_select_invite_query, $sql);

if (!$sql_select_invite) {    // check for error in query
    die(mysql_error());       // and print it
}

$invites = array();  // don't forget to make an empty array

while($invite = mysql_fetch_array($sql_select_invite, $sql)){
    // this place is not good, just make it as you do before, with checks
    $sender = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE id = '$invite[sendid]'"));

    $contest->assign("sender", $sender);
    $invites[] = $invite;
}
$contest->assign("invites", $invites);   // in your case there is no $invite 
                                         // array cause mysql_fetch_array returned
                                         // false and it is not defined before [while]

?>
```

For JS to test:

```
setInterval( function () {
  $('#invite').load('accept.php', function() {
    alert('loaded');  // it is to check content is loaded
  }).fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. but now it says No database selected

Comment: you have to do this at the beginning of a script: 1. connect to db (mysql_connect), 2. select a database (mysql_select_db). Post edited.

Comment: it has been solved but it hides the template instead of reloading it

Comment: what means hides? hides a div or ajax return empty data?

Comment: is there javascript in your ajax html template? Or maybe something in main html code? What code do you have that can hide your div?

Comment: I don't know .. theres nothing that would hide the div

Comment: I think the problem is from the jquery script .. can you check it ??

Comment: maybe you can give us a url to test it?

Comment: its not finished yet to get it online .. sorry for that, but is there another auto div reloader for jquery?

Comment: it is loaded for the first time right and on next time it is hiding. right? look at the post to test it.

Comment: its says loaded but still hiding

Comment: try to remove fadeIn function

Comment: try to put here full ajax reply

Comment: install firebug (firefox addition), click the "bug icon" at the bottom, go to the "Net" tab and check the ajax activity, especially the "Response" tab of request. And put that content here.

Comment: this is the content: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: if that is all, your php script return nothing and you should check it again. For example you can print something at the beginning of script to check it is really executing.

Comment: I print something and this is the content: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">sometext

Comment: So your queries just return nothing. Print sql from queries to the result and try to execute it in phpmyadmin. So you can check some data is returning by your queries.

Comment: but why it uses high memory usage and the computer be slow ? is there another way for java ?